# How To Access Manifest File of an App with Another App

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-hardware

How To Access Manifest File of an App with Another App. I m Designing an "Android Vulnerable Apps Detector App" so I have to access all of the Manifest Files of Entire System's Apps. Need Help About how i can read manifest with my App.

Comment: what do you actually want to do ?

Comment: I am designing an App that can detect Those Apps Which are Spyware. And also want to read manifest files of all Apps to list down Vulnerable Apps.